# Array formula using multiplication and division across 3 columns

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have Inventory data that is in the following format:

Column D | Column E | Column F

Pack Qty | Pack Price | Total Qty

This is followed by multiple rows with various numerical values, with the odd blank row.

To calculate the stock value of any particular product/line, I use =F2/D2*E2.

To calculate the total value of stock I tried {=Sum(F:F/D:D*E:E)} but it returns a #Div/0! error.

As mentioned, some rows are blank. Some items have 0 price, others have 0 stock on hand.

I would like to avoid having to total each line in a new column then total that column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply wrap your division inside IFERROR() and return 0.

```
{=SUM(IFERROR(F:F/D:D,0)*E:E)}
```

Comment: Could you maybe post a screen shot, the exact formula used and a confirmation that you have indeed pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array formula ? I used what I posted in a test workbook with no problem (both with empty cells and zeros).

Comment: Looks like it's my header row that is causing the error. If I use {=SUM(IFERROR(F2:F1000/D2:D1000,0)*E2:E1000)} it works (so long as I don't have more than 1000 rows).

Comment: I can't try it right now but try surrounding everything inside SUM() inside the IFERROR().

Comment: Me either - your solution worked perfectly for me. I don't have enough reputation points to effect the score... If there's anything I can do - happy to do it. I also see that someone else paraphrased your solution in another answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{=SUM(IFERROR(F:F/D:D*E:E,0))}
```